# Cannot load active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

I have a gem that I am trying to test some mixins in, these mixins would be used in a model to determine relationships and add helper functions, the issue I am having is that when I go to test these mixins in my gem I get: `uninitialized constant ActiveRecord (NameError)`.

In my `rails_helper.rb` (rspec 3.1) I added the following:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => 'sqlite3')
load(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/schema.rb")
```

In my `spec/models/user.rb` I then added:

```
describe "Test the user model mixin" do

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     # This is what I am testing
    include CoreModels::Models::User
  end

  context "Fail to find a user" do
    it "should return nil on a user not existing" do
      User.find_by_first_name('sally').should == nil
    end
  end
end
```

When Run I get:

```
$ bin/rspec
/Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/core_models/spec/models/user_spec.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord (NameError)
    from /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/core_models/.bundle/gems/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:325:in `module_exec'
    from /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/core_models/.bundle/gems/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:325:in `subclass'
    from /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/core_models/.bundle/gems/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:219:in `block in define_example_group_method'
    from /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/core_models/.bundle/gems/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:41:in `block in expose_example_group_alias'
    from /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/core_models/.bundle/gems/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:79:in `block (2 levels) in expose_example_group_alias_globally'
    from /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/core_models/spec/models/user_spec.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/core_models/.bundle/gems/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load'
    from /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/core_models/.bundle/gems/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/core_models/.bundle/gems/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `each'
    from /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/core_models/.bundle/gems/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/core_models/.bundle/gems/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
    from /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/core_models/.bundle/gems/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:84:in `run'
    from /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/core_models/.bundle/gems/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/core_models/.bundle/gems/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
    from /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/core_models/.bundle/gems/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rspec:16:in `load'
    from bin/rspec:16:in `<main>'
```

**Do I need to require active record?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're loading the Rails environment inside `spec/rails_helper.rb`:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__) # LOADS Rails env
require 'rspec/rails'
```

If you want to see a clean `spec/rails_helper.rb`, use the provided generator to re-create the `rails_helper` file: `rails generate rspec:install`.